# printing numbers in 2 columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I want to print 2 columns with numbers of a specific range USING PANDAS.

```
range1=2
range2=3
```

In dataframe it should print like

```
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
```

```
import pandas as pd
d1=2
d2=3
for i in range(1,d1+1):
    for j in range(1,d2+1):
        print(i,j)
        pd.DataFrame([(i,j)],columns=['proteinA','proteinB']).to_csv('prediction_test_123.csv')
```

Comment: How does the text correspond or connect to your code that involves `proteinA`, `proteinB`, and so on?

Comment: Please explain better the logic of your needed code

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not sure about this question. How does the text correspond or connect to your code that involves proteinA, proteinB, and so on. But, if you have this as input

```
range1=2 range2=3
```

And this as output

```
1 1 
1 2 
1 3 
2 1 
2 2 
2 3
```

You can achieve that by using this:

```
import pandas as pd
 
range1 = 2
range2 = 3
 
data = {
    'Column1': [i for i in range(1, range1 + 1) for _ in range(range2)],
    'Column2': list(range(1, range2 + 1)) * range1
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
print(df)
```

This is the sample output

```
   Column1  Column2
0        1        1
1        1        2
2        1        3
3        2        1
4        2        2
5        2        3
```

Here is [sample kaggle link](https://www.kaggle.com/heinzmdsiahaan/notebook-stackoverflow-com-questions-77744508)

If you want to put more detailed context, I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

range1 = 2
range2 = 3

# Generate all combinations of values from the specified ranges
data = list(product(range(1, range1 + 1), range(1, range2 + 1)))

# Create a DataFrame from the generated data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['proteinA', 'proteinB'])

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

output

```
   Column1  Column2
0        1        1
1        1        2
2        1        3
3        2        1
4        2        2
5        2        3
```

Comment: get error `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: The corrected example uses the product function from the itertools module to create all combinations of values from the specified ranges and then creates a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

I will implement the solution as follows

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = 2
d2 = 3

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['proteinA', 'proteinB'])

for i in range(1, d1 + 1):
    for j in range(1, d2 + 1):
        print(i, j)
        # Append the current combination to the DataFrame
        result_df = result_df._append({'proteinA': i, 'proteinB': j}, ignore_index=True)

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
result_df.to_csv('prediction_test_123.csv', index=False)

# Print the DataFrame
print(result_df)
```